# WPF ListBox multiple selection not raise SelectedItem on model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, inotifypropertychanged

I have a problem with my ListBox
I've set the ListBox selection mode to Multiple
The problem is that the Selected Item fire only once, and when I select other items, it is doesn't change the SelectedItem at the view model.
I'm sure its selection them because I bind a property to true when they are selected, but the selected item does not update.
For example:
Lets say I have ListBox with the following:
A
B
C
Choose A -> the ViewModel update the selectedItem to A
Choose B -> The ViewModel doesn't update the SelectedItem but I can see that B is selected 
When I deselect A, the ViewModel update the SelectedItem to null 
Someone already faced that issue?
My main goal is to keep my SelectedItem update to the one I chose
He is my code for the View:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableDagrVMEs}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDagrVME}"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="HorizontalOnly"
                     Background="Transparent"
                     BorderThickness="0">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Taken, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon , Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And ViewModel:

```
        public BaseVME SelectedDagrVME
    {
        get { return selectedDagrVME; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedDagrVME != value)
            {
                Set("SelectedDagrVME", ref selectedDagrVME, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried: TwoWay binding/UpdateTriggerSource

Comment: The behavior is correct if you select B, A is still selected. Do you need to have last selected, since you can select multiple items?

Comment: Yes , that is right I need the last selected item @Rekshino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `Multiple` selection, the `SelectedItem` will always be the first selected in your selection. To get the last selected Item you have to register for `SelectionChanged` event and access `SelectedItems` property, which contains all items from your selection. You can implement it with a behavior for you could reuse it.

**Behavior:**

```
public class ListBoxSelection : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LastSelected), typeof(object), typeof(ListBoxSelection), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object LastSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)GetValue(LastSelectedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LastSelectedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
//you can also use whatever logic if you evaluate e.RemovedItems and e.AddedItems
        if ((AssociatedObject?.SelectedItems?.Count??0)>0)
        {
            LastSelected = AssociatedObject.SelectedItems[AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Count-1];
        }
        else
        {
            LastSelected = null;
        }

    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:NameSpaceWhereBahaviorDefined"

```
<ListBox ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:ListBoxSelection LastSelected = "{Binding VMSelection}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: It is working only when I bind the LastSelected with Mode=TwoWay
Is this possible to make it work with OneWay?

Comment: Mmm I have checked that now, and not fully work... it is raise the SelectedViewVME change, but its will deselect the first item

Comment: You can bind it with `OneWayToSource`.

Comment: I can't follow you with deselect. But in this behavior you can use whatever logic(also add LastUnselected) if you evaluate `SelectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems` and `SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems`